# Building GCC and Binutils on Windows 7 x64

Tags: cygwin, gcc, c

I am trying to build GCC following the instructions in: [Building GCC](http://wiki.osdev.org/Building_GCC). At the moment I am building binutils but getting the error:

> *** BFD does not support target x86_64-unknown-cygwin.
>   *** Look in bfd/config.bfd for supported targets.
>   Makefile:2461: recipe for target `configure-bfd' failed make[1]: ***
>   [configure-bfd] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/Me/opt/binutils-2.23/build-binutils' Makefile:841: recipe for
>   target `all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

I am using cygwin64. The first error makes me to think it has to do something with me using 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Not what you want to hear, but you'd have less problems using Linux in a virtual machine than using cygwin.

Comment: Do you have a file `bfd/config.bfd` ? Which targets (to build for/on) are in that list?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want GCC there are many ports of MinGW (Minimalistic GNU for Windows) like [MinGW-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) or [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/).  Then you could install an IDE on top of those (or use the included compiler one version of the download includes!) like [Code::Blocks](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/).

Answer (score 0):

`x86_64-cygwin` is a new platform, and requires a recent binutils snapshot in order to build.  The Cygwin `binutils` source package includes the snapshot we're currently using plus the .cygport file and patchset used to build it.  But the real question is why are you building binutils when it is already available?